# WPF, Why manipulation is not reposnsive?

Tags: wpf, multi-touch

When manipulating a framework element on a canvas, it works fine, but, the manipulation events keeps get fired event after I raise my fingers, as a result the framework element will keep get manipulated ***after*** fingers are raised up from the screen.

It behaves as a stream of events keeps arriving after figures raised up.

Is there any reason that would buffer touch events ?! or is there any performance tips to consider when working with manipulation ?

For example, shall I freeze the framework element before manipulate it ?

p.s: I am not using ManipulationInertiaStarting event

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any code, it'll be hard to pinpoint.

My first suggestion would be to mark:

```
e.Handled = true;
```

after you've completed any calculations with that event.